# Unable to show *.a file in SublimeText sidebar

Tags: sublimetext

I found the sidebar hides all the .a files and I even can not find it by ctrl+t.

Maybe it's configured somewhere, do you guys have any idea?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer, it's configured in the setting-default-> "file_exclude_patterns"